# strange MVC3 controler/action behaviour

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have the following setup for my application:

```
routes.MapRoute("Default", 
                "{controller}/{action}/{idt}", 
                new { controller = "Home", 
                      action = "Index", 
                      idt = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

I am using GUIDs insted of integers for idt parameter and primary keys in my DB/Model.

I have, in the "Main" menu for my application:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Create invoice", "Create", "Invoices")
```

If I start the application and look at what path this link points to, it is a correct one: `/Invoices/Create`

But, since this path is used for the edit of the invoice as well, if I have a page open with a path `/Invoices/Create/0eb262cc-a623-41f5-9b32-fd452691f426` and then look at the path of the "main" link, it points to `/Invoices/Create/0eb262cc-a623-41f5-9b32-fd452691f426`.

What is that about? How can the "fixed" link change?
Is there something I have done in code without knowing? But even if I did I don't see why would the main link change? Where does it get the GUID in the path from?

Comment: can you put a breakpoint in? Does it display the url path when hovering over the link in your browser?

Comment: Where would you suggest I put a breakpoint? Yes, it does display the incorrect (with a GUID) path in the browser when I hover over it. That is what surprised me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Create invoice", "Create", "Invoices", new {idt = ""}, new {})
```

This should solve the length=8 problem.

Comment: This solves it. Thank you Joshua! 
But I still don't understand how and why did the "main" link pick up the href from?

Answer (score 1):

As the Route Collection contains a value for `idt` it will render the URL with that value.

you can just pass a blank value to the

```
@Html.ActionLink("Create invoice", "Create", "Invoices",new {idt=""})
```

I believe this should help solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have tried but all this does is add ?Length=8 to the end of the path, but the paths still stay the same.
I am just surprised that the link picks up the link that is currently in the browser address editor?!

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd504972.aspx) overload

```
@Html.ActionLink("Create invoice", "Create", "Invoices", null,null)
```